# Optimization of the sum of a quadratic form and the L1-norm of logarithm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning

Given the symmetric positive definite matrix $W\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ and the positive scalar $\lambda $, the objective reads
$$\min_{x} x^{T}Wx + \lambda \|\log(x)\|_1, $$
where $\|\cdot\|_1$ denotes the $\ell_1$ norm of the argument and the operator $\log(\cdot)$ is component-wise.

How can I obtain the minimum point of this objective?
Does the closed form solution exists if $W\neq I_n$?

In addition, how about the general method to solve it if the $\ell_1$ norm is replaced by some other non-smooth functions?

Comment: I assume $\log(x)$ is $(\log(x_1), \log(x_2),...,\log(x_n))$? If yes, then for any $\lambda<0$ the objective tends to $-\infty$ as $x_i\downarrow 0$ for all $i$. So you may need $\lambda\geq0$ for the minimum to exist.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have modified the statements.

Comment: May I ask what the idea behind regularizing the 1-norm of the logarithm is? Intuitively, it asks for the entries to be close to 1

Comment: I am thinking using such a penalized regression method to solve the huber regression problem from another perspective. In such a formulation, the variable $x$ actually represents the weights of observations. Keeping the entry be 1 means the corresponding observation is inlier.

Comment: If you know how to write a solution for $W=I_n$ you can also write a solution for any diagonal and positive definite $W$.  Aside from this, I highly doubt that one can say something in a more general case.

Comment: For $W=I$ you can compute $x_i = 1/\sqrt 2$.